# Clicking item in listview results in two URL requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a Jquery Mobile `data-role="listview"` to loop through several rails active model records and display them on a mobile page. Clicking each item leads to a URL (non-ajax call). Unfortuately, as it stands, upon clicking an item the request is sent twice.

**How can I make sure the URL is called once per click?**

I should add that this does not happen on desktop versions of safari or chrome. Only on my mobile device (mobile safari).

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                Header Text
               </h3>

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true"  >

                <% @camps.each do |c| %>
                    <li>
                        <a href=<%= click_url(c.guid, @pubcode.guid, @qrclick.guid) %> rel="external">
                      <%= image_tag c.icon_url %>
                       <h2><%= c.title %></h2>
                        <p><%= c.description%></p>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                <%end%>


            </ul>

        </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">      
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

**RAW HTML OUTPUT:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
            Header Text

            </h3>

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">


        <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true"  >

                <li>
                    <a href=http://www.domain.me/click/73c637925cb577a81d5d48c9b67d973b/r4t3/0aa7cf0c15de32cfc7cea3af771a0b6a rel="external">
                  <img src="https://domain.com/image1.png" />
                   <h2>Title 1</h2>
                    <p> Some text here 1</p>
                  </a>
              </li>
                <li>
                    <a href=http://www.domain.me/click/d7ab954579d27bcfc4f9f31d8e93d924/r4t3/0aa7cf0c15de32cfc7cea3af771a0b6a rel="external">
                  <img src="https://domain.com/image2.png" />
                   <h2>Title 2</h2>
                    <p>Some text here 2</p>
                  </a>
              </li>
                <li>
                    <a href=http://www.domain.me/click/d7ab954579d27bcfc4f9f31d8e93d924/r4t3/0aa7cf0c15de32cfc7cea3af771a0b6a rel="external">
                  <img src="https://domain.com/image3.png"  />
                   <h2>Title 3</h2>
                    <p>Some text here 3</p>
                  </a>
              </li>


        </ul>

    </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">      
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you post the resulting HTML after ROR manipulation?

Comment: Certainly. See changes above

Comment: it seems like an issue with mobile Safari; can you do this test: put `<a href="#" id="73c637925cb5...">` links, and attach click event handlers; are requests still fired twice?